# Postgres functions not being migrated in test environment (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql

I have the following migration:

```
class CreateNoAccentFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up

    execute <<-SQL

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION no_accent(text) RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT translate($1,'omitted', 'omitted');
    $$
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;

    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS no_accent(text)"
  end
end
```

If I run `rake db:migrate` in development, it will create the function. But it doesn't in test env. I tried with `rake db:test:prepare`, `rake db:reset`, `rake db:schema:load`, none of them will execute my `CREATE FUNCTION`. Only `rake db:drop & rake db:create & rake db:migrate` seems to work. Why?

Comment: Have you set `RAILS_ENV=test` anywhere before running those migrations?  Or, have you tried to run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yep, I did that. Forgot to mention.